# pulsar service discovery bottlenect

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-pulsar

I am reading how pulsar client discover brokers and it looks like client will consult zookeeper for the broker discovery in the background periodically: https://www.bookstack.cn/read/pulsar-2.5.2-zh/a3656d4de1a283ca.md#9hybm8. could this be a bottleneck considering there are thousands of pulsar clients? I am not quite familiar with zookeeper but the zookeeper cluster does not scale well and only contains 2 or 3 hosts usually

Answer (score 0):

Pulsar 2.5.2 is quite old.

The Pulsar Client asks to any of the Pulsar Brokers about the current owner for a topic.
The Pulsar Broker has a cache over ZooKeeper metadata, so this is usually not a problem.

Usually you can go with a 3 nodes ZooKeeper cluster for most of the Pulsar usecase. Keep an eye on Metrics in order to see if the ZooKeeper nodes are working well or are satu

Comment: then how does pulsar client discover the broker fleet? say if i don't want to use pulsar proxy which is additional ad-hoc.

Comment: You need to provide a URL to the brokers. It can either point to a single broker or be a load balancer endpoint that points to any of the brokers.